# How do I get g_print() to appear?

Tags: c++, linux, glib

I've just inherited a library from someone who left the company. It's written in C++ and g_print() is used throughout the code. I know the library is running but I can't see any debug output. Is there something I need to do to get it to show up? Does g_print() only work in debug builds? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I thought it was part of glib? http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Warnings-and-Assertions.html#g-print

Comment: Is `g_print` only used for debugging output? If so, change it to `g_message`. (Or, if you have the time, to `g_log`.)

Comment: @parsley72: Oops -- I missed the `glib` tag. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using g_log (as suggested by [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) above) then overriding it as specified in [C - gtk Logging overriding](http://www.picksourcecode.com/ps/ct/16100.php):

```
void log_handler(const gchar *log_domain,
                 GLogLevelFlags log_level,
                 const gchar *message,
                 gpointer user_data)
{
    FILE *logfile = fopen ("/tmp/debug.log", "a");
    if (logfile == NULL)
    {
        /*  Fall  back  to  console  output  if  unable  to  open  file  */
        printf ("Rerouted to console: %s", message);
        return;
    }

    fprintf (logfile, "%s", message);
    fclose (logfile);
}

uint handlerid = g_log_set_handler(NULL,
    G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL | G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION,
    log_handler,
    NULL);

if (!g_main_loop_is_running())
{
    g_log(G_LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "g_main_loop_is_running() returned 0\n");
}

if (handlerid != 0)
{
    g_log_remove_handler(NULL, handlerid);
    handlerid = 0;
}
```